# FastApi/Sqlalchemy "class is not mapped" error

Tags: python, api, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm getting this error when I try to post and create a new registry using fastapi and sqlalchemy:

> Class 'endpoints.resultados.ResultadoPruebaSerializer.InsertTResultadoRegla' is not mapped

Here is my code, thanks for your help.

**Sqlalchemy Models**

```
@as_declarative()
class Base:
  def as_dict(self) -> dict:
    return {c.key: getattr(self, c.key) for c in inspect(self).mapper.column_attrs}

class TResultadoRegla(Base):
__tablename__ = 'T_resultadoReglas'

idresultadoReglas = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
idtareas = Column(ForeignKey('T_tareas.idtareas', ondelete='RESTRICT', onupdate='RESTRICT'), nullable=False, index=True)
idreglas = Column(ForeignKey('M_reglas.idreglas', ondelete='RESTRICT', onupdate='RESTRICT'), index=True)
fecCreacion = Column(Date)
resultado = Column(String(30))

M_regla = relationship('MRegla', backref="resultados")
T_tarea = relationship('TTarea')
```

**Pydantic crud and schemas**

```
class InsertTResultadoRegla(BaseModel):

  idtareas: int
  idreglas: int
  fecCreacion: date
  resultado: str

  class Config:
    orm_mode = True


def get_regla(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(Regla).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


def check_resultados(db: Session, user_resultados: Dict):

   db_item = None

   for resultado in user_resultados:
    regla = get_regla_per_id(db, resultado["idreglas"])
    regla = regla.as_dict()   

    if resultado["resultado"] >= int(regla["minimo"]) and resultado["resultado"] <= int(regla["maximo"]):
        db_item = InsertTResultadoRegla(idtareas=1, idreglas=regla["idreglas"], fecCreacion=datetime.date.today(), resultado="CUMPLE")
        db.add(db_item)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_item)
    else:
        db_item = InsertTResultadoRegla(idtareas=1, idreglas=regla["idreglas"], fecCreacion=datetime.date.today(), resultado="NO CUMPLE")
        db.add(db_item)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_item)

  return db_item
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you are trying to add it to the db, precisely,

```
db.add(db_item)
```

You have to add it like shown below:

```
db_item = InsertTResultadoRegla(idtareas=1, idreglas=regla["idreglas"], fecCreacion=datetime.date.today(), resultado="CUMPLE")
actual_db_item = models.TableName(** db_item.dict())
db.add(actual_db_item)
db.commit()
```

Before adding the data to the db you have to convert it into a proper "db_item". I hope this solves you issue.

Comment: Edited to add some beautification.